# how to select least N elements with limited space?

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue

**The problem:**

A function `f` returns elements one at a time in an unknown order. I want to select the least `N` elements. Function `f` is called many times (I'm searching through a very complex search space) and I don't have enough memory to store every output element for the future sorting.

**The obvious solution:**

Keep a vector of `N` elements in the memory and on each `f()` search for minimum and maximum and possibly replace something. This would probably work for very small `N` well. I'm looking for more general solution, though.

**My solution so far:**

I though about using `priority_queue` in order to store let's say `2N` values and reducing the upper half after each `2N` steps.

Pseudocode:

```
while (search goes on)
    for (i=0..2N)
        el = f()
        pust el to the priority queue
    remove N greatest elements from the priority queue
select N least elements from the priority queue
```

I think this should work, however, I don't find it elegant at all. Maybe there is already some kind of data structure that handles this problem. It would be really nice just to modify the `priority_queue` in order to throw away the elements that don't fit into the saved range.

Could you recommend me an existing `std` data structure for C++ or encourage me to implement the solution I suggested above? Or maybe there is some great and elegant trick that I can't think of.

Comment: You want to keep `n least` elements, and each time you get 1 element by calling function `f()`. Am I correct? So each time insert this one element into a priority_queue (as you mentioned). If the size of this `pq` is less than N, nothing happens, but if it is greater that N (N+1) you need to `pop` the greatest element. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Insertion and removal of elements in priority_queue is not for free. My idea would be just to use as much space as I have and periodically call nth_element to get the N smallest ones.

Comment: @AKJ88 so you suggest to create a `priority_queue` (which is basically a wrapper for heap data structure) that has the greatest element in the root and to call `pop` after each `push`? Do I understand you correctly? That should preserve `N` smallest elements from being deleted, indeed.

Comment: Yes, I meant using `pq` that uses `heap`. I think it would work.

Comment: @Karlis Olte using that would require O(n) complexity while by using `pq` we can solve this problem in O(lgn) complexity.

Comment: @AKJ88 with total `K` numbers obtained from `f()`, the time complexity should be `O(K*log(N))` which is nice. This should be answer :)

Comment: @AKJ88 No, pq gives O(K*log(N)) while my suggestion depends on how much space is available.

Comment: @Karlis Olte Yes, you are right. But as he mentioned in the question `k is bigger that n` and storing `pq` with `n elements` would be a better solution.

Comment: @AKJ88 Suppose he has k/2 space, then my suggestion would give something like O(K+something linear). Of course, if he has only N space then my suggestion doesn't make any sense, but he didn't say that. He simply said that he doesn't have enough space to store them all so the answer is not co clear cut.

Comment: @Karlis Olte Again you are right, but notice that your solution would be `O(k^2)` in total and mine is `O(k*log(n))` even if `k==n` I think using a `pq` is a better solution.

Comment: @AKJ88 If k==n you just store everything and you have O(K).

Comment: @Karlis Olte Yes, but I didn't mean it that way!!!! I think you know what I mean. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find `least n` elements on total `K` elements got from calling a function. Each time you call function `f()` you get one element and you want to store `least n` elements among them without storing total `k` elements got from the function since `k` is too big.

You can define a `heap or priority_queue` to store this `least n` found so far. Just add the returned item from `f()` to the `pq` and pop the greatest element if its size became `n+1`.

Total complexity would be `O(K*log(n))` and space needed would be `O(n)`. (If we ignore some extra space required by `pq`)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option would be to use an array. Depending on the maximum allowed elements compared to `N`, there are two options I can think of:

1. Make the array as big as possible and unsorted, periodically retrieve the smallest elements.
2. Have an array of size `N`, sorted with max elements on the end.

**Option 1** would have you sort the array with `O(n log n)` time every time you fill up the array. That would happen for each `n - N` elements (except the first time), yielding `(k - n) / (n - N)` sorts, resulting in `O((k - n) / (n - N) n log n)` time complexity for `k` total elements, `n` elements in the array, `N` elements to be selected. So for `n = 2N`, you get `O(2*(k - 2N) log 2N)` time complexity if I'm not mistaken.

**Option 2** would have you keep the array (sized `N`) sorted with maximum elements at the end. Each time you get an element, you can quickly (`O(1)`) see if it is smaller than the last one. Using binary search, you can find the right spot for the element in `O(log N)` time. However, you now need to move all the elements after the new element one place right. That takes `O(N)` time. So you end up with theoretical `O(k*N)` time complexity. Given that computers like working with homogenous data accesses however (caches and stuff), this might be faster than heap, even if it is array-backed.

If your elements are big, you might be better off having a structure of `{ coparison_value; actual_element_pointer }` even if you are using heap (unless it is list-backed).